# Mongoose or Webpack: Who to Blame?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm losing my mind dealing with Mongoose and Webpack.
Some Mongoose Model functions work, but not `create`, or `save`.
Although I tested the scenario in a different file and the exact same code worked.

I am getting the error message: `_models_hike__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.default.create is not a function`

I have my model file (hike.ts) :

```
import mongoose, { models, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const HikeSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { required: function () { return this.trailName === undefined }, type: String },
  trailName: { required: false, type: String },
  year: { required: true, type: Number },
  options: {
    continuous: { required: true, type: Boolean },
    direction: { required: true, type: String },
    sameYear: { required: true, type: Boolean },
    terminus: { required: true, type: String }
  }
});

const Hike = models?.hikes || mongoose.model('hike', HikeSchema);
export default Hike;
```

And a form in my React project, where I can create a new Hike (HikeLog.tsx):

```
import Hike from '../models/hike';

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    Hike.create(this.state, (error) => { console.log('Save did not work:', error) });
}
```

The form page loads, but throws the runtime error message when the submit button is clicked.

On top of all that, VSCode shows this error for all my model functions after upgrading from mongoose 5.13 to 6.8 :

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type 
  
{
    <DocContents = AnyKeys<{ [x: string]: any; }>>
        (docs: ({ [x: string]: any; } | DocContents)[], options?: SaveOptions): 
            Promise<(Document<unknown, any, { [x: string]: any; }> & { ...; } & Required<...>)[]>;
            <DocContents = AnyKeys<...>>(docs: ({ ...; } | DocContents)[], options?: SaveOptions, callback?: Callback<...>...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

Help!

Comment: Are you trying to use mongoose in the client?

Comment: Yes, the React application make a connection with the MongoDB database, and interacts with the collection using Mongoose.

Comment: I just saw this page: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html

Is what I am trying to do not possible??

Comment: I am surprised that you can query the database in the first place. **Mongoose's browser library does not support saving documents, queries, populate, discriminators, or any other Mongoose feature other than schemas and validating documents.** If they let you do this, every user would be able to edit the entire database, now every user can only read it